# How can I restrict generating a random string only to [0-9a-Z] characters?

Tags: elixir

I'm generating a random string in Elixir as follows:

```
  len = 10
  val = :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(len)
          |> Base.url_encode64()
          |> binary_part(0, len)
```

The output of this code can contain contain hyphens and undercores which I don't want. What's a way to restrict the alphabet to only `[0-9a-Z]` characters?

Comment: Pick random chars from a valid range?

Comment: Note that doing `String.downcase` here is incorrect. It'll make `a-z` occur twice as frequently as other characters.

Answer (score 8):

I would use:

```ex
defmodule Generator do
  @alphabet Enum.concat([?0..?9, ?A..?Z, ?a..?z])

  def randstring(count) do
    # Technically not needed, but just to illustrate we're
    # relying on the PRNG for this in random/1
    :rand.seed(:exsplus, :os.timestamp())
    Stream.repeatedly(&random_char_from_alphabet/0)
    |> Enum.take(count)
    |> List.to_string()
  end
  defp random_char_from_alphabet() do
    Enum.random(@alphabet)
  end
end

iex> Generator.randstring(8)
"ydKPsdwP"
```

This will generate an arbitrary length string consisting only of `[0-9A-Za-z]`, without needing to generate random bytes via `:crypto` and filter until you get enough random bytes of the desired criteria, particularly since I suspect that weakens the strength of the randomness significantly, thus making the use of `:crypto` a moot point anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that I'll immediately follow with why you probably shouldn't be using it or any solution like it:

```
defmodule RandomString do
  @chars "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  @max String.length(@chars)-1
  defp random_char do
    ndx = Enum.random 0..@max
    String.slice @chars, ndx..ndx
  end
  def len(len) do
    list = for _ <- :lists.seq(1,len), do: random_char
    List.foldl(list, "", fn(e,acc) -> acc <> e end)
  end
end

iex> RandomString.len 12
"Z7Qb3xwzlKKj"
```

Now, why you probably shouldn't use it. What you haven't revealed is why you are generating random strings in the first place. I'll assume the highly probable scenario that you want *unique* strings for some purpose. Regardless, almost every solution to various versions of "I need random strings" questions approach the solution using a flawed specification, namely, string length. If you specify string length for random strings, you are undoubtedly guessing at your real need, uniqueness.

There are two leading ways to get strict uniqueness: deterministically (which is not random) and store/compare (which is onerous). What to do? Give up the ghost. Go with *probabilistic uniqueness* instead. That is, accept that there is some (however small) risk that your strings won't be unique. This is where understanding collision probability and entropy are helpful.

As example, consider the strings of length 12 above. How many can be randomly generated without a repeat? That question is actually underspecified. Let's rephrase it. How many can be randomly generated with less than 1 in a billion chance of a repeat? About 2.54 million. Why? Because each of the strings has a carrying capacity of about 71.5 bits of entropy.

But you didn't specify you needed to generate a potential of 2.54 million random strings with a risk of less that 1 in a billion of a repeat. Nor did you specify you needed strings of length 12. Hopefully you can see the former specification is much more explicit than guessing at string lengths.

It can be a bit pesky to calculate the amount of entropy we really need. That's where [EntropyString](https://github.com/EntropyString/Elixir) can help. Let's suppose you need to generate up to half a million Ids with the risk of repeat being less than 1 in a trillion.

```
iex> defmodule Id do
...>   use EntropyString, charset: charset64
...>   @bits entropy_bits(0.5e6, 1.0e12)
...>   def random, do: Id.random_string(@bits)
...> end
iex> Id.random
"tY0W9tyrq_P08"
```

Whoops, there that underscore you didn't want. `charset64` contains the URL and file system safe characters. For efficiency reasons, `EntropyString` only uses character sets with powers of 2 characters.

```
iex> defmodule Id do
...>   use EntropyString, charset: charset32
...>   @bits entropy_bits(0.5e6, 1.0e12)
...>   def random, do: Id.random_string(@bits)
...> end
iex> Id.random
"dTPmjTq7pgPjqBjT"
```

The strings are slightly longer, but perhaps more visually appealing. More importantly, the risk of repeat in a specified number of strings is explicit. No more guessing with string length.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the possible characters in a binary at compile time and at runtime choose one random byte from it `len` times.

```
defmodule A do
  @bytes Enum.concat([?a..?z, ?A..?Z, ?0..?9]) |> List.to_string
  def random(length) do
    for _ <- 1..length, into: <<>> do
      index = :rand.uniform(byte_size(@bytes)) - 1
      <<:binary.at(@bytes, index)>>
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect A.random(8)
IO.inspect A.random(16)
```

This should be fairly efficient as the valid char set is generated at compile time and `:binary.at` is much more efficient (O(1) vs O(n)) than selecting nth value from a list (which `Enum.random` does for lists).

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = 
  ?a..?z 
  |> Enum.concat(?A..?Z) 
  |> Enum.concat(?0..?9) 
  |> to_string 
  |> String.codepoints
len = 10
```

Here you you have a alphabet with characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 as a list of codepoints.

```
Enum.reduce((1..len), [], fn (_i, acc) -> [Enum.random(alphabet) | acc] end) 
|> Enum.join()
```

Now `Enum.reduce` will add a random character (`Enum.random(alphabet)`) from the alphabet 10 times (`(1..len)`) into a list in `acc`. Then the list is joined and you have a random string of length `len`.